# My Jekyll Post Is Throwing A 404 Error In Production

Tags: jekyll

I am using Jekyll and GitHub Pages to host a blog. However, I have the following issue:

I have created a new post in the `_posts` folder and then built the site locally using the following command: `bundle exec jekyll serve`. When I access the site on `localhost:4000`, I can click on the link to the new post and access it.

When I commit my changes to the master branch on [this repo](https://github.com/redixhumayun/redixhumayun.github.io), it builds without any errors. However, when I now click on the new post, it throws a 404 Error saying the page could not be found.

How do I resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hardcoded a link.

```
/functional/2019/03/02/make-use-of-reduce.html
```

must be :

```
/functional/2019/03/01/make-use-of-reduce.html
```

Note : Your index.html looks like it is integrally hard coded. This is not how jekyll is supposed to be used. This can quickly lead to unmaintainable code base.

Comment: Liquid also has tags for linking to pages and assets so that Jekyll will resolve all links and error out if a link doesn't work. This can help you catch broken links during the build instead of in production

https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/tags/#links

Comment: Sorry, I don't get why the link needs to have 01 instead of 02. In fact, when I try 01, it fails on my local server. 
Yeah, I need to fix my index.html not to be hardcoded. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Okay, so I tried the solution above and it works perfectly in production but fails on my local. So, why did changing it to 2019/03/01 work at all?